# Fast and reliable way to move directories from one HDD to another

Tags: clipboard, migration, rsync, transfer

I'm looking for a fast and reliable way to move some chosen directories from one HDD to another.

The case is as follows. I'm getting a new desktop system which will replace my old desktop. I want to migrate a couple of directories from the old system to the new system and I'm quite concerned about the integrity of the data. The amount of data I want to migrate is >300 GB. This might take a while to move even over 1000 Mbit/s Ethernet, so I figure the fastest way is to unplug the HDD of the old desktop (it's connected via SATA) and plug it into the new system and `cp` the data to the new system's HDD.

My question: Is this the best and most reliable way to proceed? If not, how should I proceed? Maybe I'm better off using `rsync`? I would also want to know how any solution handles permissions and how it preserves the integrity of the data.

Comment: Related http://serverfault.com/questions/47707/moving-to-a-larger-drive-in-linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd personally trust `rsync` to do the job (with `-arvx` flags - archive, recursive, verbose and one-filesystem) but if you need something extra:

```
sha256sum <(find ./original_path/ -type f -exec sha256sum {} \; | sort) | cut -d' ' -f1
# Should output something like:
# dbda116eaa459cee10b25765202c37d40b9371df52afb2ad202b13327760b251

# copy your files to ./new_path/
# Something like: rsync -arvx ./original_path/ ./new_path/

sha256sum <(find ./new_path/ -type f -exec sha256sum {} \; | sort) | cut -d' ' -f1
# Should also output:
# dbda116eaa459cee10b25765202c37d40b9371df52afb2ad202b13327760b251
```

If you're not happy with rsync, you could always tar up the files and extract them in the new location. I'd recommend checking their integrity with a similar method as above, if they're *really* important.

Comment: [Man page says](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/intrepid/man1/rsync.1.html#contenttoc11) "archive mode; equals `-rlptgoD` (no `-H`,`-A`,`-X`)". That would make `-avx` sufficient flags?